# Javascript form parser

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a generic form parser for Javascript. The idea being, a developer could drop the function onto a form and sumbit via AJAX, or do something with a form besides submit it. The result will be in the same format used in a query string.

What I have posted works, so I am basically wondering if this is a good design? What could be improved? Thanks for the help!

```
function test_submit(id){
    var results=[],form=document.getElementById(id);
    for(var i=0;i<form.elements.length;++i){
        var obj=form.elements[i];
        if(obj.name&&!obj.disabled){
            switch(obj.tagName){
            case 'SELECT':
                for(var j=0;j<obj.length;++j){
                    if(obj.options[j].selected){
                        var value=obj.options[j].value;
                        if(!value)value=obj.options[j].text;
                        results.push(obj.name+'='+escape(value));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 'INPUT':
            case 'TEXTAREA':
                var type=obj.type,value=obj.value;
                if(type)type=type.toLowerCase();
                if(type&&(type=='radio'||type=='checkbox')){
                    if(obj.checked)results.push(obj.name+'='+(value?escape(value):'on'));
                }
                else results.push(obj.name+'='+escape(value));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return results.join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd change two things.  I'd start by declaring your var's in one statement like so:

```
function test_submit(id){
    var q=[],
        p=$(id).getElementsByTagName('SELECT');
```

Second I'd use more descriptive variable names than i, p, r, n.  If you run this code through a minifier it'll do this for you.  When you come back to edit this code in a few months you'll want to know exactly what each variable is for, and using a descriptive name helps with that.

I'd also be leary of using $ in the global namespace as a variable name since a lot of the popular libraries use it and you don't want to have any collisions with those.

Comment: Understood! Made the appropriate changes. You are right, I often minify the code by hand when it is not necessary.

Comment: @steveo225 So my answer was good, just not "upvote" good?  :-)

Comment: Just taking my time...

Answer (score 2):

In regards to variables `i` and `j` they are loop index variables and can be declared in the loop alone instead of at the top.  It will clean up the code.

Example

```
for (var j=0;j<obj.length;++j){...}
```

Personally I would write it up like this describing `p` and `i` which are form elements.  In additon there is no need to duplicate code (example would be 3 identical for statments), you can gather all the form elements and concat the arrays together in one.  Then by using a switch statement you can minimize the duplicate `if`s for each element type and eliminate the need for duplicate for statements.  Have a look below. it is much cleaner.

```
function test_submit(id){  
    var params=[],
        results=[],
        form=document.getElementById(id),
        obj;  

    for(var i = 0, var formElement = form.elements[i]; i < form.elements.length; i++) {  
        if (formElement.name) {
            switch (formElement.tagName) {
                case "SELECT":
                    for(var j=0, var optionItem = formElement.options[j]; j < formElement.length; j++){  
                        if(optionItem.selected){  
                            var value = optionItem.value;  
                            if(!value) value = optionItem.text;  
                            params.push([formElement.name,value]);  
                        }  
                    }  
                    break;
                case "INPUT":
                    var type=formElement.type,
                        value=formElement.value;  
                    if(type) type=type.toLowerCase();  
                    if(type && (type == 'radio' || type == 'checkbox')) {  
                        if(formElement.checked) params.push([formElement.name,value?value:'on']);  
                    }  
                    else params.push([formElement.name,value]);  
                    break;
                case "TEXTAREA":
                    params.push([formElement.name,formElement.value]);  
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i in params) results.push(params[i][0]+'='+escape(params[i][1]));  
    return results.join('&');  
}
```

Comment: The only issue I see, `getElementsByTagName` returns an object, not array, so `concat()` doesn't work

Comment: @stevo225 actually what was I thinking you can simply iterate over form.elements.  The above code corrects my brain fart of trying to concat multiple HTMLCollections.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I like that, no using `getElementsByTagName` and they come in the proper order (not that it matters). I made a couple edits for my own taste.

Answer (score 1):

Elegant solution overall. Try jQuery as it has some nice features that can let you do some of this in one-liners.  Code-on brother.

Comment: I know, but I was looking for a non-jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1 I'd like to see it handle password fields separately: you might want to process them in some way, obfuscation, validation, strength testing etc.

2 Personally, I'd avoid using 'form' as a variable name.  Just for the sake of my own sanity, if nothing else.

3 What if the form elements have no `name`s?

Comment: 1) The best approach would be to add a callback that handles `password` fields, otherwise it isn't standard and wouldn't behave like the browser, also password fields as not always used for passwords, so strength testing and validation don't always apply

Comment: 2) I used `form` because that is what it points to, the form, also it is just a local variable, but that is really user preference

Comment: 3) That is handled. Look at the first `if` statement in the `for` loop: `if(obj.name) ...`

Comment: 3 Ah... I didn't make myself clear.  I meant: what if the form inputs are identified via ID attributes, not NAMEs?

Comment: To be sent by the browser, the name attribute is required, that is how I modeled this function, to work exactly how the browser would work if the form were actually submitted.